# THREEJS json model - uv map issue

Tags: javascript, json, three.js, uv-mapping

looking at the json file of a 3d model i saw this line

```
 "uvs": [[-3.21834,-1.65399,-3.21834,-2.57657,4.21834,-2.57657,4.21834,-1.65399,4.21834,-1.85233,4.21834,-2.7749,-3.21834,-2.7749,-3.21834,-1.85233,4.21834,0.961286,-3.21834,0.961286,-3.21834,0.038714,4.21834,0.038714]]
```

there are numbers less than 0 and greater than 1. I thought uv measurements should not be less than 0 or bigger than 1. Where is the error? They should be converted?

the geometry json data is this

```
{
    "type": "Geometry",
    "materials": [{
        "visible": true,
        "colorAmbient": [0.690196,0.690196,0.690196],
        "depthWrite": true,
        "DbgIndex": 0,
        "mapDiffuseAnisotropy": 1,
        "doubleSided": true,
        "blending": "NormalBlending",
        "wireframe": false,
        "depthTest": true,
        "specularCoef": 50,
        "mapDiffuse": "roof.png",
        "colorSpecular": [0.1,0.1,0.1],
        "opacity": 1,
        "shading": "phong",
        "colorDiffuse": [0.690196,0.690196,0.690196],
        "mapDiffuseRepeat": [1,1],
        "transparent": false,
        "DbgColor": 15658734,
        "mapDiffuseWrap": ["RepeatWrapping","RepeatWrapping"],
        "colorEmissive": [0,0,0],
        "DbgName": "roof_png_material"
    }],
    "data": {
        "skinIndices": [],
        "skinWeights": [],
        "name": "RoofGeometry",
        "normals": [0.64452,-0.593982,0.481368,0.494247,-0.563707,-0.661733,0.494247,0.563707,-0.661733,0.64452,0.593982,0.481368,-0.656606,0.597949,0.459639,-0.474654,0.561144,-0.67806,-0.474654,-0.561144,-0.67806,-0.656606,-0.597949,0.459639,-0.02356,0.642933,0.765526,-0.02356,-0.642933,0.765526,0.019044,-0.784814,-0.619373,0.019044,0.784814,-0.619373],
        "metadata": {
            "uvs": 1,
            "bones": 0,
            "materials": 1,
            "normals": 12,
            "generator": "io_three",
            "morphTargets": 0,
            "version": 3,
            "vertices": 12,
            "faces": 10
        },
        "morphTargets": [],
        "vertices": [3.43784,-3.71834,-0.861598,3.43784,3.71834,-0.861598,3.43784,-3.71834,-1.23063,3.43784,3.71834,-1.23063,-0.096621,3.71834,0.184514,-0.096621,-3.71834,0.184514,-0.096621,3.71834,-0.184514,-0.096621,-3.71834,-0.184514,-3.18641,3.71834,-0.940931,-3.18641,3.71834,-1.30996,-3.18641,-3.71834,-1.30996,-3.18641,-3.71834,-0.940931],
        "uvs": [[-3.21834,-1.65399,-3.21834,-2.57657,4.21834,-2.57657,4.21834,-1.65399,4.21834,-1.85233,4.21834,-2.7749,-3.21834,-2.7749,-3.21834,-1.85233,4.21834,0.961286,-3.21834,0.961286,-3.21834,0.038714,4.21834,0.038714]],
        "animations": [],
        "faces": [43,0,2,3,1,0,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,43,8,9,10,11,0,4,5,6,7,4,5,6,7,43,0,1,4,5,0,0,3,8,9,0,3,8,9,43,7,6,3,2,0,10,11,2,1,10,11,2,1,43,2,0,5,7,0,1,0,9,10,1,0,9,10,43,1,3,6,4,0,3,2,11,8,3,2,11,8,43,4,6,9,8,0,8,11,5,4,8,11,5,4,43,6,7,10,9,0,11,10,6,5,11,10,6,5,43,7,5,11,10,0,10,9,7,6,10,9,7,6,43,5,4,8,11,0,9,8,4,7,9,8,4,7],
        "bones": [],
        "influencesPerVertex": 2
    },
    "uuid": "2F93879C-96CB-3936-AEFC-CE9840D3057D"
}
```

how can i get exact points?

Comment: Have you exported the model from Blender?

Comment: from this website https://clara.io/view/91e15ecd-de44-4319-89ac-005482baf0ac (threejs json file). The model work well, but i dont want to preload all object, i need to merge it. but i dont understand how to do with uv coordinates

Comment: UVs are not necessarily in the range of [0,1]. The data can be transformed to achieve for example a scaling effect. If the visual result of the model is okay, you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: but if i merge two or more models i need to merge also the textures into a single texture (for good performances), then is important to transform this relatives points to absolute points

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> there are numbers less than 0 and greater than 1. I thought uv measurements should not be less than 0 or bigger than 1.

That is not the whole truth. UV-coordinates *can* be arbitrary numbers, in the end its up to the shaders to interpret them appropriately. In three.js there are parameters `texture.repeat`, `texture.offset`, `texture.center` and `texture.rotation` (see https://threejs.org/docs/#api/textures/Texture) that will be used to convert the values from the uv attribute to the values used for texture-lookups. By default, the values are used as they are.

What finally happens for values <0 and >1 depends on the settings for wrapS and wrapT (also documented in https://threejs.org/docs/#api/textures/Texture). For instance out of range values are used for texture-tiling if wrapS/T are one of the reaeat-types.

> Where is the error? They should be converted?

So there may not even be an error in this case. The numbers could just indicate an intended tiling. But to change it you need to go to where the model came from.

Comment: thanks for the answer. My problem is that i want to put the model texture into a bigger tiled texture who works in a range of 0 and 1. Is there a way to convert this relative coordinates into an absolute coordinates with different range? thanks inadvance

Comment: I don't understand "put the model texture into a bigger tiled texture who works in a range of 0 and 1". Do you mean a texture-atlas containing multiple textures?

Comment: yes. For performance reasons i want to make a single atlas with more models textures. With this atlas texture my UV coordinates going from 0 to 1. The problem is to port coordinates like: -1, +2, 4.3, etc. into this range

Comment: That is going to be difficult at best. Playing a bit with the texture-transforms (especially repeat and offset) might work. Otherwise you will probably need to go back to the editor-software and fix it there.